# PromQL query find the number of times CPU went high above 80% in last 7 days

Tags: prometheus, promql

I need to query the number of times CPU went high above 80% in last 7 days.
We have this query which will give the comparison :-

```
cpu_percent {name="abc", cluster ="def"}>30
```

and this has to be extended to 7 days range, where we need to count of values.

Any help on how to write this query for this would be greatly appreciated.

count_over_time and max_over_time is not giving the desired values.

Comment: "not giving the desired values." how is it not desired? Be more specific.

Comment: Why `count_over_time((cpu_percent {name="abc", cluster ="def"}>30)[7d])` is not what you want?

Comment: @markalex I will throw parcing error. but ```count_over_time((cpu_percent {name="abc", cluster ="def"}>30)[1w:])``` will help

Comment: Yes, sure. I always forget this colon in comments. Is it what you wanted? If yes consider writing answer.